# Filter by intermediary model field in Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create a friendship relationship between organisations. I added a `connected_organisations` field in my `Organisation` model:

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    ...
    connected_organisations = models.ManyToManyField('self',
                                                     related_name='organisations_connected',
                                                     through='Connection',
                                                     through_fields=('requester', 'requestee'),
                                                     symmetrical=False,
                                                     blank=True)
```

Then I created `Connection` as the intermediary model:

```
class Connection(models.Model):
    requester = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, related_name='requester', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    requestee = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, related_name='requestee', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_connected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The `is_connected` field indicates whether the friendship request is approved by the requestee or if the request is still pending.

I create a connection between `org1` and `org2` with:

```
Connection.objects.create(requester=org1, requestee=org2)
```

I know I can do:

`org1.connected_organisations.all()`

and this will return `org2`, but I cannot find how I can filter them by the `is_connected` field.

I tried something like:

`Organisation.objects.filter(connected_organisations__requestee=org2, connected_organisations__is_connected=True)`

but I am getting:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: is_connected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `related_names` you are using are a bit misleading as they should represent a reverse relation, so maybe change them to something like this (dont know your exact use-case). Eg. `org.connections_requested.all()` would return a queryset containg all connections where `org` is the `requester`.

```
class Connection(models.Model):
    requester = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, related_name='connections_requested', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    requestee = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, related_name='connections_joined', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_connected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

You can filter on this relations:

```
organisations = Organisation.objects.filter(
    connections_requested__requestee=org2, 
    connections_requested__is_connected=True
).distinct() # you may need that
```

Also you can directly filter on the `Connection` class:

```
connections = Connection.objects.filter(is_connected=True)
```

Comment: It appears that the query you posted on the `Organisation` model does not work in the way I expected. I would like to get all then organisations that `org1` is connected with. Something like `org1.connected_organisations.all()` but filtered by `is_connected=True`.
A query in the `Connection` model can be a solution. Just asking if I can get the same querying the `Organisation` model

Comment: When you say "all" you mean it can either be a requester or a requestee?

Comment: `org1` is the requester. I want to find all the organisations that are requestees and `is_connected=True`

Comment: `Organisation.objects.filter(connections_joined__requester=org1, connections_joined__is_connected=True).distinct()` should return the `Organisation` objects that have connection that was requested by `org1` if you stay with the naming in my answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the through model directly (that's what I typically do in this situation):

```
qs = Connection.objects.filter(requester=org1, requestee=org2, is_connected=True)
```